# If i start a new Application then this error is showing. How i can resolve it

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: Did the link in the error message itself not help? If you do not write tests (bad),  you can just delete the test app. Otherwise, make sure they use the same version. Post your gradle files for more specific advices

Comment: open you build.gradle( app) and check the version of buildToolversion & support library, both should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file the `<application>` tag.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

You can also provide other version e.g. `27.1.1`

Comment: its not resolving

Comment: please post your `build.gradle(app)` file here

Answer (score 0):

**You can force the annotation library to test using in build.gradle:**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
```

> **Another solution** is to use this in the top level file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
}
```

use any of one in Above two options, I hope it may useful to you.