# How resolve symbol of tf, root, activity

Tags: android

Having gone through lots of finding here on stackflow ([If i start a new Application then this error is showing. How i can resolve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128523/if-i-start-a-new-application-then-this-error-is-showing-how-i-can-resolve-it)) which didn`t help me and researches online, community.

ERROR MESSAGE I GOT AFTER CLEANING PROJECT

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
     Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1)
 differ.

 See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

ERROR MESSAGE I GOT AFTER REBUILDINGPROJECT

Comment: show your build.gradle (app) contents

Comment: First, error generated after cleaning project is https://imageshack.com/i/poUOgMZ0j while the image for the build.grade is https://imageshack.com/i/pnlErLCSp . Thank you as I await your assistance.